# Upgrade to Rails 5 - Deadlock happening for Sidekiq Workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, worker

I upgraded my Rails version from `4.2.5.2` to `5.0.0`. My current Sidekiq version is `4.2.10`

I have 2 models **Participation** has many **Engagement**s.

For each Engagement, I have different instances of a sidekiq worker running in parallel. And trying to update the same parent Participation.

```
participation = @engagement.participation
participation.update_attributes(
        likes_count: engagement_metrics_for_participation.likes,
        comments_count: engagement_metrics_for_participation.comments,
        shares_count: engagement_metrics_for_participation.shares,
        total_engagement: engagement_metrics_for_participation.total_engagement,
        total_impression: engagement_metrics_for_participation.total_impression
      )
```

Now the workers are getting deadlock and running forever.
So I tried http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

And updated the code

```
participation = @engagement.participation
participation.with_lock do 
  participation.likes_count = engagement_metrics_for_participation.likes
  participation.comments_count = engagement_metrics_for_participation.comments
  participation.shares_count = engagement_metrics_for_participation.shares
  participation.total_engagement =   engagement_metrics_for_participation.total_engagement
  participation.total_impression = engagement_metrics_for_participation.total_impression
  participation.save
end
```

But still facing the same issue. I need your help to solve this issue.

Comment: This deadlock should not happen, it's a single row update, active record can handle that blocking, what makes you think that there is a deadlock ?

Comment: I think it's more of a timeout issue, does the update timeout saying that it didn't receive the lock within 5 seconds ?

Comment: Make sure you're using rails 5.0.2 which has several fixes

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady : Timeout is also not happening. When I tried to update manually from console, its not happening. thats why I thought its a deadlock... And I cleared all workers and tried from console again, it was working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should consider upgrading rails to 5.0.2(latest when posting this answer), since 5.0.0 could not be called stable and a lot of bug fixes came soon after its release.

Secondly, since the model code has not been shared i can only tell you that there is something in the Model thats causing the updation to fail, maybe some validation errors, callback errors, etc.

A workaround i could suggest is, if you don't care about callbacks or validations for this particular method is that you could use `update_columns` instead of `update_attributes` which would skip model validations and wont trigger any callbacks.